# Lossless splitting and concatenation of video

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-editing

I would like to split a video file into several video files in a way that would make it possible to recreate exactly the same original video file later. Can it be done?

The videos I have have the .mov extension and are encoded using H.264/MPEG-4 AVC. I'm looking for something that can be run from a Unix command line, but other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, I believe `.mov` files are a proprietary Apple format. I mean you can check over at the http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I can try that if I don't get answers here. But open-source tools, such as ffmpeg, seem to handle my file just fine. I just don't know how to split it without losing any information.